# Parent component re-renders cause duplicate children component renders

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with URL like `product/:id` and it has some children components. When I route and change param `id` I get data from server again, set state, and re-render the page. But the children components are not re-rendered, they are rendered again ( So now I have twice same HTML Code ).

I don't know why it happened.

This is my children component:

```
listProductCardHTML = this.state.randomList.map((card, index) => {
    return (
        <ProductCard cardContent={card} key={index}>
        </ProductCard>
    )
})
```

And this is JSX:

```
<div className="box-product product-carousel" id="related-carousel">
    {listProductCardHTML}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that when you get routed to your `product/:id`, you push a new child to the `randomList` array.

Therefore the code `listProductCardHTML = this.state.randomList.map((card, index)` generates multiple JSX elements and are rendered.

Please check you `setState` method and check if `randomList` is being set correctly.